# .bash_profile permission denied

Tags: bash, console

I'm trying to make one of my first projects published with github but I'm having trouble testing the build locally.

I'm following the steps here:
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/

and I am stuck on the following command line runs:

```
echo "source $(brew --prefix)/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "source $(brew --prefix)/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "chruby ruby-3.1.2" >> ~/.bash_profile # run 'chruby' to see actual version
```

Each time I run the first one, I get the following error:

-bash: /Users/account/.bash_profile: Permission denied

This is all very new to me and honestly I have no clue what I'm doing when it comes to the console. I am on MacOS Monetory and my shell is bash. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Something is weird with your bash_profile's ownership or permissions or something. What does `ls -leO@ ~/.bash_profile` show?

Comment: I would also add the `-d` option to the suggested command by @GordonDavisson, to catch the unlikely case that your `.bash_profile` happens to be a directory. In any case, your commands are odd: To modify your bash configuration, use a text editor an paste the desired settings into it (preferably with an explanatory comment), instead of using `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Something has corrupted or changed ownership to root your `.bash_profile` script.

Open Terminal.app and do these:

- `mv -f ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile`
- `cp ~/.bash_profile.old ~/.bash_profile`

These commands show not produce errors.

Now try to re-run your scripts to append to `.bash_profile`.